# Creating a bar chart based on number or rows over 100k using javascript with d3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Having a little trouble creating this bar chart from an excel file. Right now it is showing the total population of each state, I want it to show a count of the number of counties over 100k population per state. My current code is:

```js
function reform(dataset) {
  var State = [];
  var PBS = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    idx = State.indexOf(dataset[i].State);
    if (idx >= 0) {
      PBS[idx][1] += dataset[i].population;
    } else {
      PBS.push([dataset[i].State, dataset[i].population]);
      State.push(dataset[i].State);
    }
  }
  return PBS
}

function DrawVis(dataset) {
  var w = 1000;
  var h = 200;
  var barPadding = 2;
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset).enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * (w / dataset.length);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return h - 15 - (4 * parseInt(d[i, 1] / 1000000) + 1);
    })
    .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
    .attr("height", function(d, i) {
      return (4 * parseInt(d[i, 1] / 1000000) + 1);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return "rgb(116, 52, 235)";
    }); //" + Math.round(d * 10) + "

  svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset).enter().append("text").text(function(d, i) {
      return d[i, 0];
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return i * (w / dataset.length) + 5;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return h - 5;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "6px")
    .attr("fill", "green");
}
var dataset
var rowConverter = function(d) {
  return {
    "County": d.county,
    "State": d.State,
    "population": parseInt(d.population),
  };
}
d3.csv("USpopulation.csv", rowConverter, function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
  dataset = data;
  console.log(data);
  dataset = reform(dataset);
  console.log(dataset);
  DrawVis(dataset)
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
```

My csv file looks like this:
[image]
*it has over 3000 rows

The current code output looks like this:
[image]

I am super lost on how to change the bars from total population of each state to number of counties over 100k. Also I am running it on localhost.
The bars should represent the number of counties per state over population of 100,000. I have no clue how to count that and have looked pretty hard. I am also not great at javascript, any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that your problem is with data wrangling. That comes with experience, but is also language agnostic - the same knowledge can be used in Python and in JavaScript.

In this case, forget that d3 even exists. The following code uses only plain JavaScript. d3 offers convenience functions, but there is absolutely no need to use it.

You only have to be clear from the start on what your data looks like now, and what it should look like when you're done.

```js
// Generate some data. 6 states with 10 counties, each with a random population
// between 0 and 200,000
const data = "ABCDEFG".split("").map(function(state) {
  return d3.range(10).map(function(i) {
    return {
      State: state,
      County: state + " - " + i,
      Population: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200000)
    }
  });
}).flat();

function reform(dataset) {
  // Your dataset should be an array of states, with for each state a count
  // [ { State: "AL", Count: 20 } ]
  // First, we start with an object { AL: 20 }, and we only convert it at
  // the last minute
  var resultObj = {};
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    var row = dataset[i];
    // Ignore all rows with too little population
    if (row.Population < 100000) {
      continue;
    }

    // `(resultObj[row.State] || 0)` means that if the state is not present
    // 0 is used instead
    resultObj[row.State] = (resultObj[row.State] || 0) + 1;
  }

  console.log(resultObj);

  // And now we form it into an array of the correct structure
  var result = [];
  var states = Object.keys(resultObj);
  for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    var state = states[i];
    var count = resultObj[state];
    result.push({
      State: state,
      Count: count
    });
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(reform(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```